# is it a good idea to call viewdidload in a method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I was just curious weather it is a good idea to call viewdidload a method like in an ibaction or something of that kind.

thanks, 
TC

Answer (score 7):

Check:
[UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> **viewDidLoad**
>
> This method is called after the view
>   controller has loaded its associated
>   views into memory. This method is
>   called regardless of whether the views
>   were stored in a nib file or created
>   programmatically in the loadView
>   method. This method is most commonly
>   used to perform additional
>   initialization steps on views that are
>   loaded from nib files.

The `viewDidLoad` method is automatically triggered.
Generally there is no need to trigger `viewDidLoad` yourself.
If you need to run specific code both after loading and button-click, do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self specificFunction];
}

- (IBAction)theButton:(id)sender {
    [self specificFunction];
}


- (void)specificFunction {
    // This code wil run after the view has been loaded
    // and when the user clicks the button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The disadvantage of calling `ViewDidLoad` is , the superclass methods would be called as it has `[super viewDidLoad]`, which is not a good idea . 
It's better to have a separate methods and call them whenever necessary .