# how to Reaload viewDidLoad in a method , Not call again such as [self viewDidLoad ];

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

i want to reload ViewdidLoad in a method But now want to call again like [self viewDidLoad ];

is this possible?

Comment: you can't do this manually instead use viewWillAppear

Comment: I'm damn agree with what Marvin said. Use viewWillAppear...

Comment: This is not the correct way to reload your view. Instead on reload values which are to be reflected on the view.

Comment: Here is my answer to a similar question  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37268012/5553647

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of calling `viewDidLoad:` make another method (`newMethod`) and move all the code in it that needs to be called then from

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self newMethod];
}
```

Then from your code where you want to call `viewDidLoad:` call

```
[self newMethod];
```

---

#### Swift version

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.newMethod()
}
```

Then from your code where you want to call `viewDidLoad:` call

```
self.newMethod()
```

Answer (score 3):

Copy all code in - (void)viewDidLoad then paste in viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  //paste your viewDidLoad codes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can call from any method but if you post your scenario then it is better to reply

```
[self viewDidLoad];
```