# Accessing NSDictionary object outside of ASYNC callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, unirest

I am using UNIRest to make a call and return a JSON object to my app. I have it returning the proper data as a NSDictionary and it logs our perfect. I am now trying to take that data and display it inside of my view. I cannot use my dictionary outside of the callback.

I have been digging around here on StackOverflow for similar results and posts related to variables. I feel it is a scope issue with it being limited to inside of the callback block.

My header file: (UIViewController)

> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *tideData;

My implementation:

```
@interface TideDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation TideDetailViewController

@synthesize tideData;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     //    tideData = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];


    // location is working, I removed it for testing to call a static string for now

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSString *locationQueryURL = @"http://api.wunderground.com/api/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/tide/geolookup/q/43.5263,-70.4975.json";
    NSLog(@"%@", locationQueryURL);


    [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
        [request setUrl: locationQueryURL];
    }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // This is the asyncronous callback block
        self.code = [response code];
        NSDictionary *responseHeaders = [response headers];
        UNIJsonNode *body = [response body];
        self.rawResults = [response rawBody];

        // I tried this as self as well
        tideData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.rawResults options: 0 error: &error];

        // this logs perfectly.
        NSLog(@"tideData %@", tideData);

        // tried setting it to the instance
        //self.tideData = tideData;


    }];

    // returns null
    NSLog(@"tideData outside of call back %@", self.tideData);


    // this is where I will be setting label text for now, will refactor once I get it working
   // rest of file contents........
```

I have tried a good amount of items related to scoping, clearly just missing the mark. Any ideas? I have searched setting global variables, etc. Been stuck on this for a bit now.

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: What's the problem with `self.tideData = tideData;`? Of course you need to tell the view to update itself after assigning the value.

Comment: Hey @rmaddy - after I set ```self.tideData = tideData``` reload the view? I dont want to be adding a subView correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, reload the view. Remember, the completion block is called long after the view has been displayed initially.

Comment: @rmaddy Along these lines? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867722/how-to-reaload-viewdidload-in-a-method-not-call-again-such-as-self-viewdidloa

Comment: That seems about right.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see `nil` is because you are logging it too soon: when you call

```
NSLog(@"tideData outside of call back %@", self.tideData);
```

the `get:asJsonAsync:` method has not received the results yet.

You can fix this problem by adding a setter for your property, and adding some special handling to it, like this:

```
-(void)setTideData:(NSDictionary*)dict {
    _tideData = dict;
    NSLog(@"tideData outside of call back %@", _tideData);
}
```

This method will be called from the asynchronous code when you do the `tideData = ...` assignment.

Comment: Ah I see. I added that in real quick and it is working. I see the log output. I have ```@synthesize tideData``` up top. With that set, I can remove the ```_``` inside of the method?

Comment: So now when I want to drill in to my object my ```tideData``` object. I would need to extend that outside of that method. For instance, i cannot use ```dict``` outside of that method correct? 

Ultimately trying to do something like this: ```NSDictionary *tideInfo = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"tide.tideSummaryStats"];```

Comment: Does this allow us to set tideData to anything when we call this method?

```[self setTideData:dictionaryObjectHere]```

Shooting for extracting an item and displaying it in label text

Comment: @Coughlin Yes, you should be able to do that, unless that json callback happens in a wrong thread, in which case you would need to change the way you call the setter from the block. Did you try changing a label text from this setter? It should just work.

Comment: Ok great, so when I call that line above ```dictionaryObjectHere``` now stores ```tideData``` ?

Comment: @Coughlin I do not understand your last question. Where does `dictionaryObjectHere` come from? Once you store the `dict` in the `_tideData` variable, you can use it at any time after that.

Comment: Should have re wrote that sorry. Outside of the ```setTideData``` method we set the returned JSON to ```tideData``` - and the method then stores the ```dict``` - I guess its the role of ```dict``` that I am confused on.

Comment: So we saying ```dict``` is equal to ```_tideData``` - then we can use ```dict``` to call on ```valueForKey```, etc.? Is that more accurate? Dont mean to be wordy, just trying to grab an understanding, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Coughlin `dict` is the name of the formal parameter passed to the `setTideData:` method. Whatever the caller passes from the outside of the method, becomes `dict` on the inside of the method.

Comment: Ok, I see. And by breaking it up in to that method allows the request to finish we set the ```tideData``` and we can call where needed

Comment: @Coughlin Correct, the asynchronous method would finish, but the dictionary would remain available in your object for future reference.

Comment: Cool, thank you! Last comment, an example would be say ```NSArray *tideSummaryStats = [[self setTideData:_tideData] valueForKey:@"tide.tideInfo.tideSummaryStats"];``` -- then later I can grab an item convert to string update to label text, etc.

Comment: @Coughlin No, you don't need to call the setter. The data is already in the `_tideData` variable, so all you need is `NSArray *tideSummaryStats = [_tideData valueForKey:@"tide.tideInfo.tideSummaryStats"];`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the object on main thread:

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setTideData:) withObject:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.rawResults options: 0 error: &error] waitUntilDone:NO];


- (void)setTideData:(NSDictionary*)dict {
self.tideData = dict;
}
```

Comment: What does this allow when we set it on the main thread? @Ratan Does it tell it to set on some type of global/higher level (I know that is broad)