# RemoveFromSuperview doesn't seemed to remove the subview i created

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

I am testing with swift code to make a QR code scanner and i can't get a red frame to be removed on reset.

I have the following code in viewDidLoad

```
// Red box highlight
    qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    viewForLayer.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
    viewForLayer.bringSubviewToFront(qrCodeFrameView)
    // End box highlight
```

Now when a QR is scanned this shows the border:

```
let barCodeObject = self.previewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObject as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as!  AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        qrCodeFrameView.frame = barCodeObject.bounds
```

And with a reset button i like to remove the border and be able to rescan. With the following i am able to rescan but the last red rectangle is still visible

```
        @IBAction func resetButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.refreshView()
    }

    func refreshView(){
        //remove frame border
        qrCodeFrameView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.viewDidLoad()   
self.viewWillAppear(true)
    }
```

I added a breakpoint at qrCodeFrameView.removeFromSuperview() and it stops there, but i don't exactly know what too look for. (I mean with variables i get it but for removeFromSuperview i don't know what suppose to be happening??)

regards

[edit]
Ok i followed the tips to never call viewDidLoad an viewDidAppear directly and i created a seperate function cameraLayerWithBorder(), but still the red border is shown on reset/refreshView?

```
 func cameraLayerWithBorder(){
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

//capture image code .......

        // Previewlayer with camera added to a placed layer 
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession);
        previewLayer.frame = viewForLayer.bounds;
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
        viewForLayer.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer);


        // Red box highlight
        qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        viewForLayer.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
        viewForLayer.bringSubviewToFront(qrCodeFrameView)
        // End box highlight

         captureSession.startRunning();
    }
```

and i edited refreshView()

```
        func refreshView(){
        print("reset")
        //remove frame border
        qrCodeFrameView.removeFromSuperview()
       // self.viewDidLoad()
//        self.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.cameraLayerWithBorder()
    }
```

and part of this function sets the red border

```
    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    captureSession.stopRunning()

    if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {//fula says let verwijderen
        let readableObject = metadataObject as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject;

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        // add red borders
        let barCodeObject = self.previewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObject as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        qrCodeFrameView.frame = barCodeObject.bounds
        // end add red borders
        foundCode(readableObject.stringValue);
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the view in debug (the red border is UIWindow > UIView > UIView > UIView

[image]

[EDIT 2]
Workable solution, thanks to Ibrahim i overlooked the obvious and i had to add the frameborder code part from function cameraLayerWithBorder to  captureOutput function

```
 // Red box highlight

        qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        viewForLayer.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
        viewForLayer.bringSubviewToFront(qrCodeFrameView)
        // End box highlight
```

still not sure if this is the way

Comment: Never call `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` yourself.

Comment: tx, i have outcommented both and added a function with the code i originally had in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 1):

Only remove from superview will not work, you need to remove preview layer also. Please try below, hope it will work.

```
videoPreviewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
view.sendSubview(toBack: self.qrCodeFrameView!)
self.qrCodeFrameView?.removeFromSuperview()
captureSession?.stopRunning()
```

Let me know if this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `main queue` when dealing with UI manipulations:

#### Objective C

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    [qrCodeFrameView removeFromSuperview]
 })
```

#### Swift

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    qrCodeFrameView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: This is not needed. It's all being done on the main thread already.

Comment: the answer is right, you have to do this in the main queue if your are dealing with Server request. 

SWIFT 4 
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.XXX.removeFromSuperview()
        }

Answer (score 0):

You remove the view from its superview in `resetButtonTapped()`, but then you call the function `cameraLayerWithBorder()` afterwards. In that method you add the `qrCodeFrameView` again.

Don't call `cameraLayerWithBorder()`afterwards, instead write new code with what you wanna do in `resetButtonTapped()` or create a new method and call that after you remove it.

***--- First Answer ---***

Try delete `viewDidLoad()` & `viewWillAppear()`, i think its the reason. Not 100% sure. But in this case you dont have to call those methods, but if you want to call `viewDidLoad` use this approach

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9868106/1842694

Comment: hi Ibrahim, i have added function with the code (see my edit) but still the border is shown

Comment: hmmm, but cameraLayerWithBorder() has the code i like to be performed. See it as a kind of initial state and after the code has been scanned i like to go back to the first state, hence i thought i could reuse the code. But i see what you mean

Comment: Hmm so you still want the ```qrCodeFrameView``` to be shown when you click reset, but just without the red border? Can you be more specific